# iPhone - difference between NSString and NSMutableString regarding memory usage

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a block of text that have to be parsed. It is kind a template like

> "Dear $name, we need the registration number of your $vehicle, bla bla"...

imagine this 1000 characters long, with a lot of key variables, like $name, $vehicle, etc.

This text is stored on a `#define`

At run time, I have to parse this template and other 20 like that, replacing the key variables with the real values, like "Dear John, ....".

I was using a `NSString` variable to store the initial text and then these lines

```
NSString *start = TEMPLATE1;
start = [start stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:NAME withString:realName];
start = [start stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:VEHICLE withString:realVehicle];
```

and so one and the code is working fast and well, but someone suggested using a `NSMutableString` for the start variable, as it would use less memory.
Is this correct?
Will it worth the change?

Comment: It would be a pretty negligible difference if any with that small amount of text.

Comment: So when should anyone use NSMutableString?  I never have and the docs don't seem to specify any use cases for it.

Comment: @chown the texts are huge, about 10,000 characters that have to be parsed (counting all 20 templates).

Comment: @Javy yes, NSMutableStrings are sweet to append text.

Comment: @Digital Oh, i though you were saying it was only 1000 characters long total.  My mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be reasonable to do this:

```
NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:TEMPLATE1];
[text replaceOccurrencesOfString:NAME withString:realName options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
[text replaceOccurrencesOfString:VEHICLE withString:realVehicle options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])];
```

But if your code is already "working fast and well", I wouldn't bother changing it.